# How can I call vegaEmbed many times quickly?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, web-worker, vega, vega-lite

I'm using Vega-Lite to embed charts in a Vue.js project. But, some times, when I have to embed a list of charts, my application breaks a little.

I actually iterate over a list of Vega-Lite specifications, embedding each one. There is a more efficient way to do it?... Maybe something using Web Workers, like [Vue-Workers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-worker)...

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the error codes that are generated when you mentioned that your app breaks a little? It is hard to provide some answer / guidance if there's no mention of the specific issue that you were facing. Can you also post some codes that you were using to render  the vega charts